# Get the new link that results from the first link by php

Tags: php, soundcloud

I have the following url

https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https://soundcloud.com/chrisbjerken/you-still-have-my-heart

and I want it to be changed to the following url when I click on it:

https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/221607450

how ho get the new url by PHP?

because I need the ID "221607450" after tracks.

Answer (score 0):

Example :

```
 $s = 'https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/221607450';
    
            $r = explode('/', $s);
            var_dump(end($r));
```

OR

```
var_dump($_GET);
```

Comment: Thank you, but the question is, how do I get the new second link? I own the first. Is there a way to get the second link via PHP

Comment: $sekurl = $_GET['url'];

Comment: Where do I put the first link to return the second link to me?

Comment: Show some code - i not understand what are you want

Comment: I WANR PUT THIS URL IN PHP (  https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https://soundcloud.com/chrisbjerken/you-still-have-my-heart) AND PHP RETURN THE NEW ONE (https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/221607450)